# Change subfloat spacing

Tags: spacing, subfloats, subfig

I tried to remove the spacing around [H] figures by setting `\intextsep` to `0pt`, but this sadly doesn't change the spacing around subfloats.

Is there a way to do this (other than manually adding a negative `\vspace`)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

% remove spacing around H figures
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
  Sample text.

  % REMOVE THIS SPACING!

  \begin{figure}[H]
    \subfloat[Sample caption.]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{1.png}}}%
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Sample caption.]{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{2.png}}}%
  \end{figure}

  Sample text.

  \begin{figure}[H]
    \minipage{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
    \endminipage\hfill
     \minipage{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
    \endminipage
  \end{figure}

  Sample text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that using the `subcaption` instead of the `subfig` package does the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

% remove spacing around H figures
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
  Sample text.

  \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
      \caption{Sample caption.}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
      \caption{Sample caption.}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}

  Sample text.

  \begin{figure}[H]
    \minipage{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
    \endminipage\hfill
     \minipage{0.475\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
    \endminipage
  \end{figure}

  Sample text.
\end{document}
```